# Angular directive not being processed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a fairly simple set of directives, one being the parent while the other being the child. A simple "list and list-items" kind of set. But, the child one isn't being used. At all. Its link function isn't even being called.

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pe2engcw/

You'll see a `0` popping up in the HTML, which reflects the number of child items being processed, and added to the parent controller. There should be a `2`.

I've tried rewriting the link function to a compile function that returns the link function. The compile function does get called, but the link function still doesn't. I've tried with and without `replace: true` (but honestly, I need the DOM to be clean, so I'm gonna leave it in). I've tried combinations with `transclude: true` (because hey, you gotta try something). None of that triggers the link function to even get called, let alone do what I need it to do.

The child directive doesn't have a template. I know this. This is intentional. It doesn't need a template, because it's not going to render anything. The corresponding elements are just data. The parent directive will render them appropriately, which is why the parent directive does have a template.

I thought this was a super-simple setup without any exotic constructs... so I might be missing something. But what?

Comment: If you provide it a template, why would you assume it's children wouldn't be overriden?

Answer (score 0):

Without using `ng-transclude` to tell angular where to wrap the existing content you will effectively wipe out the child elements with the new template. Since they are gone that explains why your link function wasn't firing.

Following modifications make it work although I'm sure you will want to change the template

```
app.
  directive("swSystemsLinks", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: { },
      replace: true,
      transclude:true,// let angular know to transclude content
      controller: [ "$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.links = [ ];

        this.addLink = function(name, url, icon) {               
          $scope.links.push({
            name: name || "",
            url: url || "",
            icon: icon
          });
        };
      }],
      /* use `ng-transclude` to point out where to wrap content into template */
      template: "<div>{{ links.length }}<div ng-transclude></div></div>"
    };
  });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pe2engcw/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: But the thing is, I don't need or want that extra div in there. Also, the child elements do not produce any html by themselves, so it seems like a waste to call in angular's transclusion motor, and then discard it.

Comment: then what is the template for? If there is no template you don't need transclude

Comment: Well, like I said, the child elements are data. They provide the parent directive with data so it can render things. Indeed, this is why I assumed I don't need transclusion, but I *do* need those elements processed.

Comment: For now, I've added a link function to the parent directive that removes the `ng-transclude` element that I've added from your suggestion. It feels hacky and overkill-ish, but it does result in a clean DOM - which by extension, will result in cleaner CSS. Here's my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pe2engcw/3/

Comment: That makes no sense at all. It removes your child directive elements

Comment: I agree with @charlietfl, this doesn't make sense.... I don't think we understand what you're trying to do. If your child elements are not needed in the dom, and are just data, why aren't you just doing this in the controller, or in the parent directive?

Comment: I don't know. All I want is for the child elements to get processed *somehow*, but I don't want them to end up in the DOM. If there's a better way to do that, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Why can't you do whatever it is in controller then? You have access to all the data there. We don't really know what it is you are trying to do since you hard coded the example

Comment: What I'm trying to do, is to render items. Simple as that. But, I don't want those items to render themselves in any way shape or form. I want the parent directive to do all the rendering.

Comment: If you want more help, provide code and data example. Issue is likely easy to resolve but you haven't been clear from the beginning what the higher level issue is. This seems to have turned into a classic `X-Y problem`

Comment: All code that is part of the problem is in the fiddle. I don't understand what else you want me to provide...? It's *just* elements that *just* shouldn't render any html, and I *just* need the data defined in them. Here, that's a property called "name".

Comment: and there is no need to use the view or directives to do that, simply put business logic in controller

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing your children. I know that sounds very dramatic, but it's true.  You can add transclude:true to your parent directive so the children gets put in the dom. In addition you add a ng-transclude to an element in your template, to say where the children-elements shall be put. This is only necessary if you have a template on your parent directive.

I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pe2engcw/2/

```
app.
  directive("swSystemsLinks", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: { },      
      transclude: true,
      controller: [ "$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.links = [ ];

        this.addLink = function(name, url, icon) {
          $scope.links.push({
            name: name || "",
            url: url || "",
            icon: icon
          });
        };
      }],
      template: "<div>{{ links.length }}<div ng-transclude></div></div>"
    };
  }).
```

Comment: See my comment on charlietfl's answer. Yours is identical ;)

Comment: Yeah I know, we answered minutes apart :) Then I would remove the template on the parent (swSystemsLink), if it's only there for debugging purposes. You can print out the links length in the children if you bind links to the controller object instead. this.links = [];

Comment: The template isn't there just for debugging. I put it there to indicate the number of children, just to prove that the directive for the child elements isn't working. Eventually the parent directive will be rendering the children using a template.